# Initializing an ArrayList with an array in a single line

Tags: java, arrays, list, data-structures

I have an array of `String`s and I'm looking to be able to do something along the lines of

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"this", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings"};
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>( arrayOfStrings );
```

or

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
listOfStrings.addAll( arrayOfStrings );
```

I know I can do both of these if my strings are already in a collection, and also that I can iterate through the array and add them individually, but that one's a little bit messy.

Is there any way to initialise a `List` (or any collection for that matter) with an array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method, which takes a `var-args`, and returns a fixed-size `List` backed by an array. So, you can't add any element to this list. Further, any modification done to the elements of the `List` will be reflected back in the `array`.

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"this", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings);
```

or: -

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings");
```

---

If you want to increase the size of this list, you would have to pass it in `ArrayList` constructor.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings));
```

Comment: Is the list `unmodifiable`?You mean you can not add elements.The list contents are modifiable

Comment: @Cratylus. Yeah, I mean we cannot add any element in that. I'll update the answer to remove confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Arrays.asList()` static method.

For example:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"this", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings);
```

Note, that you create a fixed-size list "backed up by array" in such a way. If you want to be able to expand it, you'll have to do the following way:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"this", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings));
```

Comment: Note that it creates a fixed-size list, so if you specifically want an `ArrayList` you need to do `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))`.

Comment: @RussellZahniser That's a valid note. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use asList()

Arrays.asList(T... a) 
          Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

This may not fall exactly in your question, but may be worth a consideration.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings");
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<List<String>> arrayStringMega = new ArrayList<List<String>>(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("1","2","3"),Arrays.asList("2","3","4")));`

Comment: It's just another duplicate answer about `Arrays.asList`

Comment: If you take a closer look. It's been done in one line :)